# Get the maximum of difference of two fields in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm newbie to mongoDB. Here I face with an error while I want to get the maximum value of the difference of two fields.

Here is the structure of data saved in database:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("52b3833bd3e98582d2bfb628"),
    "author" : {
        "name" : "Graydon Hoare",
        "email" : "graydon@gmail.com"
    },
    "title" : "Why Rust ditched pure functions",
    "body" : "sth",
    "url" : "http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.rust.devel/3674/focus=3855",
    "date" : ISODate("2013-04-30T13:23:00.000Z"),
    "starred" : 105,
    "ratings" : [ 
        3, 
        5, 
        3, 
        2, 
        4, 
        1, 
        3, 
        3, 
        3, 
        2, 
        3
    ],
    "comments" : [ 
        {
            "user" : "tr0lltherapy",
            "upVotes" : 18,
            "downVotes" : 2,
            "text" : "sth",
            "replies" : [ 
                {
                    "user" : "thedeemon",
                    "upVotes" : 10,
                    "downVotes" : 0,
                    "text" : "sth"
                }, 
                {
                    "user" : "mcandre",
                    "upVotes" : 0,
                    "downVotes" : 5,
                    "text" : "sth"
                }, 
                {
                    "user" : "lacosaes0",
                    "upVotes" : 30,
                    "downVotes" : 6,
                    "text" : "Particular emphasis on memory safety."
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "user" : "hypster",
            "upVotes" : 30,
            "downVotes" : 2,
            "text" : "tl;dr everybody was type-fu fighting",
            "replies" : [ 
                {
                    "user" : "homoiconic",
                    "upVotes" : 15,
                    "downVotes" : 0,
                    "text" : "Here comes the Big Boss, Hu! Simon Peyton-Jones."
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "tags" : [ 
        "Rust", 
        "Computer", 
        "Programming"
    ],
    "draft" : true,
    "published" : true
}
```

What I want is to get the value of maximum of the subtract of `upVotes` and `downVotes` in `replies` and `comments`.

```
db.getCollection('links').aggregate([
    {$project: {
        _id: "$author",
        maxVote: $max: {
                $subtract: ["$comments.upVotes", "$comments.downVotes"]
                }
            } 
     }
])
```

I don't know how to fix it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [$map](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/index.html) to get the difference for each comment (using [$subtract](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/index.html)) and then run `$max` on the output from mapped `comments`. Additionally you need another nested `$max` to get the differences from `replies`, try:

```
db.col.aggregate([
    {
        $project: {
            maxVote: {
                $max: {
                    $map: {
                        input: "$comments",
                        as: "comment",
                        in: {
                            $max: {
                                $concatArrays: [
                                    [ { $subtract: [ "$$comment.upVotes", "$$comment.downVotes" ] } ],
                                    {
                                        $map: {
                                            input: "$$comment.replies",
                                            as: "reply",
                                            in: { $subtract: [ "$$reply.upVotes", "$$reply.downVotes" ] }
                                        }
                                    }
                                ]
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

prints:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("..."), "maxVote" : 28 }
```

Comment: I want to retrieve the maximum value of differences in comments and replies together. In other words, each comment has some upVotes, downVotes and has some replies with the same fields, so how to implement it?

Comment: @MostafaGhadimi I see, just modified my answer

Comment: Off the top of my head nothing clever comes to my mind, probably you can have another field which will be an array that can contain values from both 'A' and 'B' and create unique index on that new field but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for